# How do I sort items on insert into treestore and have them displayed sorted in treepanel? extjs 4.07

Tags: extjs, tree, controller, extjs4, treepanel

I want to know how to insert items into a treestore sorted, if there is a way within extjs to do this. I then want to have the items appear in a treepanel sorted, although there may already be some nodes in the treepanel;

So, that question may be, how do I have a treepanel reload what it is displaying based on what is within my store. Let me be clear, I do not want to reload the store from some datasource. I want to reload the panel to reflect what is contained within the store. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real default way to do this.  What your going to have to do is create an empty store on the page that uses the same model as the tree, something really simple like this:

```
var mySortStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    model: "MyTreeStore",
    data:  []
});
```

Then when you go to add the node to the tree, use this function instead:

```
function addNodeSorted(node, childToBeAdded){
    //clear the store from previous additions
    mySortStore.removeAll();
    //remove old sorters if they are dynamically changing
    mySortStore.sort();
    //add the node into the tree
    node.appendChild(childToBeAdded);
    var cn = node.childNodes,
        n;

    //remove all nodes from their parent and add them to the store
    while ((n = cn[0])) {
        mySortStore.add(node.removeChild(n));
    }

    //then sort the store like you would normally do in extjs, what kind of sorting you want is up to you
    mySortStore.sort('height', 'ASC');//this is just an example

    //now add them back into the tree in correct order
    mySortStore.each(function(record){
        node.appendChild(record);
    });
}
```

Comment: SO, what exactly is happening here. We have to reload the whole store to have the treepanel update? Why does it work this way. A co-worker of mine doesn't understand why I am doing it this way. I told him it's the simplest way I could find and he isn't convinced.

Comment: Also, where should I be creating that sorStore?

Comment: The sortstore should be created and used wherever the same model is used that pertains to the treestore.  This is syntactically the simplest way of doing it, although probably not the most optimized for speed, but unless you have 300+ nodes under a parent node I would think the performance impact is negligible.  The reason this looks so complex is because the library doesn't provide a way to do it by default and it in itself is not simple to do.

Comment: If your coworker has a simpler way to do it, use his way... I would.

Comment: node interface has a sort method which allows you to implement a function to define sorting behavior of it's childNodes

Comment: wow, I can't believe I missed that one in the docs, good work.

Comment: You weren't the only one who missed it, but it certainly cleaned things up for me

Comment: Bbb your comment about NodeInterface's sort should be an answer. Helped just as much as the accepted answer.